# Can we estimate VAR model using monthly data for 7 years?

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression

I am interested in estimating the long run relation between electricity shortfall and industrial output with other variables. It forms a 6*6 matrix. Can I get reliable estimates? I am very much worried about my research due to data limitation.

Comment: Could you explain what the matrix is composed of? Also, what kind of model do you intend to use (multiple linear regression, VAR model, ...)?

Comment: In our model, we have a total of six variables:Y_t, CD_t, E_t,π_t,X_t,〖Un〗_t, which are Quantum index of manufacturing as a proxy for GDP, Circular debt, Electricity shortfall, CPI based inflation rate, Exchange rate and Rate of unemployment respectively.  A μ_t= Bϵ_t. A and B are (6*6) matrices, whereas ϵ_t are structural shocks.

Comment: Still not getting what model you are using. What is $\mu_t$? Is it a vector including the six variables? Is this model identified? If I premultiply both sides of the equation by a matrix C, the equation will still hold but the values of matrices CA and CB will be different than those of matrices A and B.